# What are the machines at the grocery store entrance called?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

What are the machines at the grocery store entrance called?

I'm talking about the 'CoinStar' machines specifically, but what is the general name for them?

I'm planning on creating one, but to do research on the topic, I'm pretty sure I need to know what it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[coin cashing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerwall)* (WP)

> Outerwall Inc. (formerly **Coinstar**, Inc.) is an American company with a network of … coin cashing machines. Outerwall operates Coinstar machines which deduct a fee for conversion of coins to banknotes …
>   Outerwall also produces machines that provide prepaid credit cards, cellular phone cards, tickets to concerts, and e-payment kiosks. It is also developing kiosks for pharmaceutical dispensing.
>   The typical Coinstar coin cashing kiosk is green and the size of a large vending machine. They are located at grocery stores, drug stores, larger merchants, banks or other retail locations.

Look for 'coin counting machines,' ''coin counters/ sorters,' 'automatic coin counter,' 'coin exchange machines,' even 'money machine!'

This may interest you in the design:
How Products Are Made, Volume 4, **[Change Machine](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-4/Change-Machine.html)**

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably call them something with "kiosks" involved. Like "automated kiosks," perhaps? That's not really descriptive unless the person actually knows what you're talking about, which isn't super helpful, but I'm not sure there is a generally acceptable term for them. "Grocery store kiosks" might be a good search. That's a serious "might," but it could at least be a good starting point.

Comment: *Kiosks* are exactly what Coinstar calls them on their website: https://www.coinstar.com/